# Where is return statement required in recursive functions?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I read this article on recursion on topcoder and in the solution of maze solver, I don't understand why "return true" statement is required after the "if exploreMaze()" statements, since they are already given after the base conditions.

```
function exploreMaze(maze[][],x,y)
{
  // If the current position is off the grid, then
  // we can't keep going on this path
  if y>8 or y<1 or x<'A' or x>'H' then return false

  // If the current position is a '*', then we
  // can't continue down this path
  if maze[x][y]=='*' then return false

  // If the current position is an 'E', then 
  // we're at the end, so the maze is solveable.enter code here
  if maze[x][y]=='E' then return true

  // Otherwise, keep exploring by trying each possible
  // next decision from this point.  If any of the options
  // allow us to solve the maze, then return true.  We don't
  // have to worry about going off the grid or through a wall - 
  // we can trust our recursive call to handle those possibilities
  // correctly.

  if exploreMaze(maze,x,y-1) then return true  // search up
  if exploreMaze(maze,x,y+1) then return true  // search down
  if exploreMaze(maze,x-1,y) then return true  // search left
  if exploreMaze(maze,x+1,y) then return true  // search right

  // None of the options worked, so we can't solve the maze
  // using this path.

  return false
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't link to off-site code. Include the relevant part of the code in the body of the question.

Comment: Because you function must *always* return a value. Using a  `return` without an argument is undefined behavior.

Comment: So if the first time it succeeds (the first move hits the base case) should it continue to explore the others or just return true at the point? Draw a maze on a paper, for each time you make a recursive call, physically add something to a basket and keep adding on top it first (stack) - for each return take it out of the basket starting from the top first. See if that helps.

Comment: @AlainMerigot 1) No, a function is not required to return a value. 2) `return;` is not UB

Comment: The code on the other site is not `c++` or `c`

Comment: @4386427 ...if (and only if) the function has return type `void`. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff True... and we don't know anything about that...

Comment: @4386427 But in the sample program on the site given by the OP using  `if exploreMaze(whatever)` if `exploreMaze`  returns nothing would be UB (once properly translated to C or C++).

Comment: @AlainMerigot I don't look at code posted via links. Here there is no code so there is no context.

Comment: @AlainMerigot Can you plz look into it now.

Comment: @SamerTufail if all the moves are checked and none of them are possible then it would return false and otherwise if we reach end 'E' then the base condition is already given. So why return true after all move statements?

Comment: `if exploreMaze(maze,x,y-1) then return true` if the recursive call returned true ( it found a solution) it pushes causes the true to propagate up otherwise it returns false. Without this propagation the original calling function would not know the solution was found.

Comment: The code is inorrect! Please see my edited answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418483/733637)) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base case is here:

```
if maze[x][y]=='E' then return true
```

– if you reached the endpoint, you managed to solve the maze, hence the maze is solvable, and you return `true` to say that.

Now if you reached *some* point which is not the endpoint yet, and recursively explored the rest of the maze (this is what happenned in the `if` instruction), and you got `true` from  the recursive call, then that recursive call managed to reach the endpoint. Hence the maze is solvable – return `true`.

**NOTE**

The code presented is *incorrect*: it can't properly handle an unsolvable maze.

If the maze is not solvable, either due to the absence of the `'E'` position:

```
******
*....*
******
```

or the absense of an appropriate path:

```
**********
*........*
*.********
*......*E*
**********
```

the code will recur 'forever' until the stack overflow, and then crash.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the maze is created as a text block.  * is used to indicate wall, or out of bounds. The letter 'E' is used to show the exit of the maze.  It probably looked like this:

```
********************E**
*......*......*......**
*.********.*******.****
*.....*......*........*
*.*************.*****.*
*..*............*****.*
***********************
```

From the line y<1 y>8, the dimensions should be 8 high, but you get the idea.  When the position is the letter 'E', then the exit is found, and the maze is solved.  'A' and 'H' are used to indicate width of some sort. I don't quite get that, but it's the same idea.

The recursion works like this. Take my starting point, say x=7,y=6.  If it's the exit, then we're successful. If it's on a wall, we failed. if it's out of bounds, we failed, now check all four locations around me and do the same thing. If any of those four locations found an exit, then we're successful.

If the maze is solvable, then we get 'true', if a branch is solvable, then we get true.  If the maze isn't solvable from a given start position, then false is returned, and if a branch doesn't lead to the exit, false is returned.

Comment: At what step will return true after "if exploreMaze()" be executed.

Comment: When x and y map to the position of 'E' in the text maze.

Comment: If you want to more clearly understand recursion, I would suggest a simpler example - say a tree walk.  It's calling itself over and over, and by the structure, it does work.